# Subsetting a dataframe in R using key words that appear in the first 100 words

Tags: r, subset, keyword-search

I have a dataframe that contains information on news articles (headlines, dates, content, etc). I would like to subset this dataframe by filtering the content of the news articles using key words. However, I would like to apply those key words within the first 100 words of the content.

So far, I have been able to subset the dataframe by identifying the keywords in each of the articles as shown below. However, I need to identify those key words within the first 100 words of each article.

```
#Dataframe
df_tiempo_noticias_farc1

#Filtering the dataframe by using key words
key_words_filter <- c("acuerdo de paz", "acuerdos de paz", "acuerdo con las farc", "acuerdos con las farc",
                      "acuerdo entre el gobierno y las farc", "acuerdo entre las farc y el gobierno", 
                      "proceso de paz", "diálogos con las farc", "diálogos en la habana", "diálogos de la habana",
                      "diálogos de paz", "negociación con las farc", "negociaciones con las farc", "negociación en la habana",
                      "negociaciones en la habana", "negociadores del gobierno y las farc", 
                      "negociadores de las farc y el gobierno", "plebiscito", "firma de la paz")

subset_tiempo_kwords <- df_tiempo_noticias_farc1[grep(paste0(key_words_filter, collapse = "|"), df_tiempo_noticias_farc1$content),]
```

**Here is some data sample**

```
  > dput(subset_tiempo_kwords[1:2, 5])
[1]con la firma del nuevo acuerdo entre el gobierno y las farc y su refrendación en senado y cámara, las cartas están echadas y las apuestas, hechas. pero más allá de quién gane la partida, el resultado es que vamos al año y medio más difícil en la historia reciente del país.pese a que hubo cambios de fondo en el acuerdo final, como era previsible, no hubo acuerdo con los del no (no vale ya discutir si se les podía haber dado más juego o si, en el fondo, solo lo querían para dar largas). esto significa que la verdadera refrendación de lo acordado entre el gobierno y las farc se traslada a las elecciones del 2018.el país sigue tan dividido como antes del plebiscito (aunque más apático con la paz, a cuya firma ha asistido cinco veces desde junio). la polarización y el encono que signaron la campaña del plebiscito solo fueron el abrebocas de lo que nos espera hasta las elecciones presidenciales, que serán el veredicto final sobre lo acordado.el gobierno y las farc decidieron firmar el acuerdo y pasarlo por el congreso. el bloque del no ya anunció que opondrá, dentro del capitolio, recursos legales, como buscar un referendo por firmas, y fuera de él, llamados que bordean la ruptura institucional, como la revocatoria del congreso o la resistencia civil.todo indica que, aunque menos legítimo, el camino del congreso se escogió como más seguro, contando con las mayorías oficiales (que ya se exhibieron en el 75-0 de la refrendación en senado). arriesgada apuesta, pues esa vía puede terminar no siendo ni legítima ni segura.otro plebiscito sería largo, costoso y polarizador, como dice el gobierno. pero el legislativo no solo confiere menos legitimidad que cualquier consulta popular para refrendar el acuerdo, sino que es una de las instituciones más desprestigiadas del país. refrendar con una proposición, la fórmula de menor jerarquía en la mecánica legislativa, solo acentuará ese pecado de origen.pero la fragilidad de la refrendación vía congreso no es lo más grave. las grandes sorpresas pueden ser las de la implementación.el congreso es una vía de alto riesgo para los acuerdos. el gobierno ha puesto velas, cirios y candelabros para que la corte constitucional reviva la famosa ‘vía rápida’ para que los parlamentarios aprueben, veloces y sin cambios, lo que les proponga para implementar el acuerdo. pero, como pintan las cosas, es más probable que le toque irse por la vía ordinaria.con lo cual tomaría todo el 2017 poner a funcionar la jurisdicción especial para la paz, blindar jurídicamente el acuerdo y aprobar las leyes para hacerlo realidad. y los congresistas podrían introducir modificaciones inesperadas –como ya lo sugirió cambio radical respecto al sistema de justicia–. esto haría más traumático y lento el proceso de desmovilización de las farc. y pondría en lo más álgido de la campaña electoral un proceso de paz inconcluso y lleno de tensiones.ni el plebiscito ni la renegociación del nuevo acuerdo zanjaron la división entre partidarios del sí y del no. el gobierno, con sus mayorías en el congreso, puede lograr ahora blindar constitucionalmente lo acordado. pero otro gobierno, con otras mayorías, puede echar todo abajo –y a eso se la juega el bloque del no para el 2018–.todo este año y medio que falta hasta las elecciones presidenciales estará signado por esa polarización, que está tan viva como antes del plebiscito. el trámite de lo acordado en el congreso no hará sino agudizarla. y, mientras tanto, estará en curso, con más o menos sobresaltos, el complejo proceso de desmovilización, dejación de armas y reintegración de las farc.la ‘crispación nacional’ se va a profundizar hasta que en el 2018 se decida finalmente quién ganó: la paz o el no.\r* * * *\ry el eln... para enero.álvaro sierra restrepocortapalo@gmail.com@cortapalo, 

[2] la comisión interamericana de derechos humanos (cidh) aplaudió este jueves la firma y aprobación del acuerdo de paz con las farc que fue ratificado esta semana tanto por la cámara como por el senado colombiano.\ren un comunicado expedido desde washington, el ente hemisférico expresa a su vez su beneplácito por los esfuerzos del gobierno por incluir en el nuevo acuerdo algunas propuestas de quienes se oponían al documento en general.\r\"la comisión interamericana reconoce los esfuerzos del estado para la renegociación del acuerdo de paz, en atención al pluralismo efectivo necesario en una sociedad democrática. la comisión ve con beneplácito que, tras tomar en cuenta las propuestas planteadas por los grupos que cuestionaron el acuerdo anterior y llamaron a votar en contra del mismo en el plebiscito del 2 de octubre pasado, colombia haya llegado a un nuevo acuerdo para la terminación del conflicto con las farc - ep\", dice la cidh. (le puede interesar: 'debemos presentar la ley de amnistía la próxima semana': mininterior)\ren el comunicado la comisión menciona la reunión que sostuvieron recientemente con el presidente juan manuel santos en la que se discutió \"la actual precariedad del cese al fuego y la futura implementación del acuerdo en colombia\".\rsegún este órgano, el presidente de la cidh, james cavallaro, le expresó a santos que el ente que encabeza continuaría monitoreando que la implementación del acuerdo se realice dentro del \"respeto y garantía a los estándares interamericanos\" de derechos humanos.\r\"la comisión mantiene su convicción respecto a que la consolidación de la paz es un requisito indispensable para el ejercicio y respeto de los derechos humanos. la cidh continúa comprometida con la búsqueda de la paz en colombia y dispuesta a colaborar en este esfuerzo, y en ese marco dará seguimiento a la implementación del nuevo acuerdo, en el marco de sus funciones\", dijo caravallo.\ren el comunicado, no obstante, la cidh resalta que el texto del nuevo acuerdo que les entregó santos en la reunión cambió antes de ser aprobado. (además: lo que viene tras la refrendación de la paz en el congreso)\raunque no menciona a cuál ajuste se refiere, la única modificación conocida al nuevo acuerdo que se llegó con las farc fue uno en el que se eliminó un artículo que hacía referencia a la responsabilidad de los militares por las acciones de sus subalternos.\ral respecto, el comisionado para colombia, josé de jesús orozco, destacó que \"continuarán dando seguimiento a la situación de los derechos humanos en colombia, a fin de que la implementación efectiva del acuerdo permita satisfacer los estándares internacionales de verdad, justicia y reparación en el contexto de transición hacia la paz\".\rpor su parte el embajador de colombia ante la oea, andrés gonzález, resaltó el apoyo de la comisión como \"de la mayor importancia porque el gobierno ha querido que el acuerdo de paz cumpla con todos los estándares internacionales. su declaración es esclarecedora: el camino más apropiado para prevenir las graves violaciones de derechos humanos es la terminación del conflicto armado. de acuerdo con gonzález el respaldo de la cidh representa \"una sólida columna de legitimidad jurídica internacional. todo el sistema interamericano se ha pronunciado por la paz de colombia como la paz de américa. primero, el consejo permanente de la oea por unanimidad. ahora la entidad rectora del continente en derechos humanos\".\rsergio gómez masericorresponsal de el tiempowashington ")
```

How can I do it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is an an example to create a new variable "Sentance_new" that selects the first 9 words in the original sentence. You can simply change 9 to 100. Then you filter based on the key words you want.

```
 Df_1 <- data.frame(Sentance=c("Hello how are you doing today acuerdo de paz? 
         Can you give me a hand with this work."))

 Df_2<-Df_1 %>%
    mutate(Sentance_new=word(Sentance,1,9)) %>%
    filter(str_detect(Sentance_new, 'acuerdo de paz'))
```

EDITED ADDITION:
DF_1 is your dataset with the text from numerous news sites. Just keep adding 
"str_detect(news_2, "acuerdos de paz") | " from your key words. "|" is OR.

```
DF_2<-DF_1 %>%
  mutate(news_2=word(news,1,100)) %>%
  filter(str_detect(news_2, "acuerdo de paz") |
     str_detect(news_2, "acuerdos de paz") | 
     str_detect(news_2, "acuerdo con las farc"))
```

Comment: I have edited my post so you can see two examples of my data. I am not sure if I understand your answer since my data is not just one sentence but many. In other words, each row I want to check is a news article. I need to apply the keywords within the first 100 words of each news article. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes this is what my code executes. It works row by row to filter bases on your keywords you want. I did not enter them all, you can add them all.

Comment: I applied the following code `new_df<- subset_tiempo_kwords$content %>%
mutate(news_2=word(subset_tiempo_kwords$content,1,100)) %>% filter(str_detect(news_2, "acuerdo de paz") |
           str_detect(news_2, "acuerdos de paz") | 
           str_detect(news_2, "acuerdo con las farc"))` but got an error. It says I cannot use `mutate` for an object of class `character`.  Which class should I use instead?

Comment: with the example I made the text was a factor

Comment: I applied your code. If I add a high number, it seems to be working. However, when adding low ones (for some reason I do not understand) it does not get the content I need. With the following example, it should get the first sample I shared in the post as the word "acuerdo" is the sixth one. However, it does not. `new_test2 <- subset_tiempo_kwords%>%
  mutate(content2=word(subset_tiempo_kwords$content, start = 1 , end = 10)) %>% filter(str_detect(content2, "acuerdo"))`  Do you know what can it be?

Comment: Jose, so you are saying the parsing of the first 100 words works. However, now you want to parse the first 10 words?    new_df<- subset_tiempo_kwords$content %>% mutate(news_2=word(subset_tiempo_kwords$content,1,10)) %>% filter(str_detect(news_2, "acuerdo de paz") | str_detect(news_2, "acuerdos de paz") | str_detect(news_2, "acuerdo con las farc"))

Comment: Yeah. However, if you try that code, it does not work. And that is what I do not get what is the issue here (since it works with higher numbers like 100)

Comment: what is the error message? did you try renaming your dataframe to something new?

Comment: I figured there were many blank spaces at the beginning of each row. And they were being counted as words; that is the reason why the code did not properly work when the limit were 10 words. I will share my final answer wich was a mixed of your response and @Corey Pembleton

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, use the first filter to create a subset, and create a regex pattern using the or operator "|" between each key word:

```
df <- tribble(~A,
              "[1]con la firma del nuevo acuerdo entre el gobierno y las farc y su refrendación en senado y cámara, las cartas están echadas y las apuestas, hechas. pero más allá de quién gane la partida, el resultado es que vamos al año y medio más difícil en la historia reciente del país.pese a que hubo cambios de fondo en el acuerdo final, como era previsible, no hubo acuerdo con los del no (no vale ya discutir si se les podía haber dado más juego o si, en el fondo, solo lo querían para dar largas). esto significa que la verdadera refrendación de lo acordado entre el gobierno y las farc se traslada a las elecciones del 2018.el país sigue tan dividido como antes del plebiscito (aunque más apático con la paz, a cuya firma ha asistido cinco veces desde junio). la polarización y el encono que signaron la campaña del plebiscito solo fueron el abrebocas de lo que nos espera hasta las elecciones presidenciales, que serán el veredicto final sobre lo acordado.el gobierno y las farc decidieron firmar el acuerdo y pasarlo por el congreso. el bloque del no ya anunció que opondrá, dentro del capitolio, recursos legales, como buscar un referendo por firmas, y fuera de él, llamados que bordean la ruptura institucional, como la revocatoria del congreso o la resistencia civil.todo indica que, aunque menos legítimo, el camino del congreso se escogió como más seguro, contando con las mayorías oficiales (que ya se exhibieron en el 75-0 de la refrendación en senado). arriesgada apuesta, pues esa vía puede terminar no siendo ni legítima ni segura.otro plebiscito sería largo, costoso y polarizador, como dice el gobierno. pero el legislativo no solo confiere menos legitimidad que cualquier consulta popular para refrendar el acuerdo, sino que es una de las instituciones más desprestigiadas del país. refrendar con una proposición, la fórmula de menor jerarquía en la mecánica legislativa, solo acentuará ese pecado de origen.pero la fragilidad de la refrendación vía congreso no es lo más grave. las grandes sorpresas pueden ser las de la implementación.el congreso es una vía de alto riesgo para los acuerdos. el gobierno ha puesto velas, cirios y candelabros para que la corte constitucional reviva la famosa ‘vía rápida’ para que los parlamentarios aprueben, veloces y sin cambios, lo que les proponga para implementar el acuerdo. pero, como pintan las cosas, es más probable que le toque irse por la vía ordinaria.con lo cual tomaría todo el 2017 poner a funcionar la jurisdicción especial para la paz, blindar jurídicamente el acuerdo y aprobar las leyes para hacerlo realidad. y los congresistas podrían introducir modificaciones inesperadas –como ya lo sugirió cambio radical respecto al sistema de justicia–. esto haría más traumático y lento el proceso de desmovilización de las farc. y pondría en lo más álgido de la campaña electoral un proceso de paz inconcluso y lleno de tensiones.ni el plebiscito ni la renegociación del nuevo acuerdo zanjaron la división entre partidarios del sí y del no. el gobierno, con sus mayorías en el congreso, puede lograr ahora blindar constitucionalmente lo acordado. pero otro gobierno, con otras mayorías, puede echar todo abajo –y a eso se la juega el bloque del no para el 2018–.todo este año y medio que falta hasta las elecciones presidenciales estará signado por esa polarización, que está tan viva como antes del plebiscito. el trámite de lo acordado en el congreso no hará sino agudizarla. y, mientras tanto, estará en curso, con más o menos sobresaltos, el complejo proceso de desmovilización, dejación de armas y reintegración de las farc.la ‘crispación nacional’ se va a profundizar hasta que en el 2018 se decida finalmente quién ganó: la paz o el no.\r* * * *\ry el eln... para enero.álvaro sierra restrepocortapalo@gmail.com@cortapalo, ",
              "[2] la comisión interamericana de derechos humanos (cidh) aplaudió este jueves la firma y aprobación del acuerdo de paz con las farc que fue ratificado esta semana tanto por la cámara como por el senado colombiano.\ren un comunicado expedido desde washington, el ente hemisférico expresa a su vez su beneplácito por los esfuerzos del gobierno por incluir en el nuevo acuerdo algunas propuestas de quienes se oponían al documento en general.\r\"la comisión interamericana reconoce los esfuerzos del estado para la renegociación del acuerdo de paz, en atención al pluralismo efectivo necesario en una sociedad democrática. la comisión ve con beneplácito que, tras tomar en cuenta las propuestas planteadas por los grupos que cuestionaron el acuerdo anterior y llamaron a votar en contra del mismo en el plebiscito del 2 de octubre pasado, colombia haya llegado a un nuevo acuerdo para la terminación del conflicto con las farc - ep\", dice la cidh. (le puede interesar: 'debemos presentar la ley de amnistía la próxima semana': mininterior)\ren el comunicado la comisión menciona la reunión que sostuvieron recientemente con el presidente juan manuel santos en la que se discutió \"la actual precariedad del cese al fuego y la futura implementación del acuerdo en colombia\".\rsegún este órgano, el presidente de la cidh, james cavallaro, le expresó a santos que el ente que encabeza continuaría monitoreando que la implementación del acuerdo se realice dentro del \"respeto y garantía a los estándares interamericanos\" de derechos humanos.\r\"la comisión mantiene su convicción respecto a que la consolidación de la paz es un requisito indispensable para el ejercicio y respeto de los derechos humanos. la cidh continúa comprometida con la búsqueda de la paz en colombia y dispuesta a colaborar en este esfuerzo, y en ese marco dará seguimiento a la implementación del nuevo acuerdo, en el marco de sus funciones\", dijo caravallo.\ren el comunicado, no obstante, la cidh resalta que el texto del nuevo acuerdo que les entregó santos en la reunión cambió antes de ser aprobado. (además: lo que viene tras la refrendación de la paz en el congreso)\raunque no menciona a cuál ajuste se refiere, la única modificación conocida al nuevo acuerdo que se llegó con las farc fue uno en el que se eliminó un artículo que hacía referencia a la responsabilidad de los militares por las acciones de sus subalternos.\ral respecto, el comisionado para colombia, josé de jesús orozco, destacó que \"continuarán dando seguimiento a la situación de los derechos humanos en colombia, a fin de que la implementación efectiva del acuerdo permita satisfacer los estándares internacionales de verdad, justicia y reparación en el contexto de transición hacia la paz\".\rpor su parte el embajador de colombia ante la oea, andrés gonzález, resaltó el apoyo de la comisión como \"de la mayor importancia porque el gobierno ha querido que el acuerdo de paz cumpla con todos los estándares internacionales. su declaración es esclarecedora: el camino más apropiado para prevenir las graves violaciones de derechos humanos es la terminación del conflicto armado. de acuerdo con gonzález el respaldo de la cidh representa \"una sólida columna de legitimidad jurídica internacional. todo el sistema interamericano se ha pronunciado por la paz de colombia como la paz de américa. primero, el consejo permanente de la oea por unanimidad. ahora la entidad rectora del continente en derechos humanos\".\rsergio gómez masericorresponsal de el tiempowashington")

#do this for the whole list
key_words_filter <- c("acuerdo de paz|acuerdos de paz|acuerdo con las farc")

df %>% 
  mutate(selection = str_extract(A, "^.{100}")) %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., pattern = key_words_filter )))

A tibble: 1 x 2
  A                                                  selection                                         
  <chr>                                              <chr>                                             
1 "[2] la comisión interamericana de derechos human~ [2] la comisión interamericana de derechos humano~
>
```

You can also explore using filter_at or filter_if if you don't want all columns filtering, you can specify the column you want.

Comment: I applied the code and got this `Warning message:
In stri_length(string) :
  invalid UTF-8 byte sequence detected. perhaps you should try calling stri_enc_toutf8()` What does it mean?

Comment: It means that the data you're using needs a different encoding for a different language. Latin languages often need encoding to be specified. if you're importing from a csv, you can use ```read_csv("data.csv", readr::locale(encoding = "latin1"))```

Comment: I am not importing from csv. My dataframe is an object located in my global environment. How can I change the encoding?

Comment: You should open another question for that, or do some research on it, encoding can be a bit tricky. try this ```dplyr::mutate_if(df, is.character, .funs = function(x){return(`Encoding<-`(x, "UTF-8"))})``` encoding into UTF-8 or latin1

Comment: @JoseDavid if the answer is correct, could you mark as a solution?

Comment: I still have not been able to execute the code (so I do not know if it works). I have changed to different encodings ("latin1" and "ISO-8859-1") with no results. Indeed, I checked the content column and every row is on "UTF-8" so I do not understand what the issue is. Is there any other way to do this without getting that warning message?

Comment: Okay, check my edited response. I can't verify but you might want to test it.

Comment: I tested it. I got the following error `Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` I tried using the exact same code you provided and also I adapted it to my own dataframe. Both cases I got the same message

Comment: OKAY it works now. using filter_all() and make sure you set the regex pattern in your key words how I have it, all in one string like ```key_words_filter <- c("acuerdo de paz|acuerdos de paz|acuerdo con las farc")```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200249/discussion-between-corey-pembleton-and-jose-david).

Comment: Although the code seems to be working now, there is still an issue. If I change the value of "100" for any other (10, 1, 500, etc.), the number of articles I get is always the same. It appears, then, that the condition of the number of words is not really taken into account. I applied the code to my entire corpus (which is 8689 articles); No matter the number condition, I will always get 4129 as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was produced based on the other two responses to this post

```
#Creating the key words filter 
    key_words_filter2 <- c("acuerdo de paz|acuerdos de paz|acuerdo con las farc|acuerdos con las farc|acuerdo entre el gobierno y las farc|acuerdo entre las farc y el gobierno|acuerdos de la habana|proceso de paz|diálogos con las farc|diálogos en la habana|diálogos de la habana|diálogos de paz|negociación con las farc|negociaciones con las farc|negociación en la habana|negociaciones en la habana|negociadores del gobierno y las farc|negociadores de las farc y el gobierno|plebiscito")
```

In order for the key words filter to work, it has to be in one line string as above and each key word separated by the condition | "OR".

```
#Subsetting the dataframe within 100 words
subset_tiempo_100 <- subset_tiempo_kwords%>%
  mutate(content2=word(subset_tiempo_kwords$content, start= 1, end = 100)) %>%
  filter(str_detect(content2, key_words_filter2))
```